# Using event listener to update the react state, application hangs because of high frequency render(probably). How can I optimise this?

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron, ipc

I am trying to emulate ArduinoIDE serial monitor with an Electron-React app. My application hangs while updating the react component if the data frequency(data coming from the hardware) is very high.

I am reading the data from my hardware using [serialport module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport). The redux dispatch function  (which is updating the state of the respective SerialMonitorComponent) is fired through the data event listener of serialport module.

I tried to implement Uncontrolled React Component using refs. But still, couldn't find a solution.

I get the data using serialport module in my backend(electron part), then I send the data via IPC communication to my renderer(React part) which eventually fires the dispatch function to update the state. Something like below:

```
ipc.on('updateSerialValue', (event, val) => {
    this.props.onUpdateSerialValue(this.props.serialValue + String.fromCharCode(...val));
});
```

After this I update my component something like,

```
<textarea
      disabled
      className={classNames(styles.serialMonitor)}
      value={serialValue}
/>
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to re render on every single change? If not, you could debounce or throttle your callback to limit the amount of times it gets called in a period of time.

Comment: I thought of the same. But it is a serial monitor, it should show the values as it reads. That's the reason I couldn't use throttle or debounce.